# Writing styled-jsx without selector

Tags: next.js

Without specifying/wrapping with a selector (`button {}`), the following `styled-jsx` style declarations will work. The button is properly styled which is great. However, usage like this is not documented in website so i wonder if this syntax is officially supported and safe to use?

```
<button>
  <style jsx>{`
    background-color: red;

    :hover {
       background-color: #ccc;
    }
  `}
  </style>
Test
</button>
```

Another example, using resolve tag that works too:

```
const { className, styles } = css.resolve`
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

`styled-jsx` uses `stylis` [css preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylis) under the hood. This is how `styled-jsx` transforms content of a style tag:

```js
    transformedCss = transform(
      isGlobal ? '' : getPrefix(dynamic, staticClassName),
      plugins(css, pluginsOptions),
      { splitRules, vendorPrefixes }
    )
```

Note, that `transform` here is a wrapper function around `stylis`.

Thus styles declared inside `<style jsx>` tag will be wrapped with dynamically generated class and then transformed with `stylis`.
In your case `styled-jsx` will produce this css:

[image]

*If you use `global` selector no class selector will be added to the generated code and so produced css wont be applied to any elements on the page.*

From my point of view it won't be a mistake to use styles without a selector, however, you should do it carefully with a `<style jsx>` tag because in this case styles will be applied to every element inside a component.

Using this feature with `css.resolve` looks much more safe since you may manually pick the elements to apply css.

As far as I know, the official documentation misses the explanation of such an important detail.